# How to identify maps that are $A$ to $A$, given that you know their relations $R$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How would I go about working out given a proposition whether or not the relation is a map of $A$ to $A$? An example question would be $R = \{ (x,y) | x = y + 2 \}$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a map from $A$ to $A$?

Comment: In terms of the identity map? If its not then i don't believe i do.

Comment: So read the [Wikipedia article on *functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) aka *maps*. Just the introduction is enough.

Comment: Just in case the article doesn't make it clear: a relation $R\subset A\times A$ is (the graph of) a *map* from $A$ to $A$ if and only if the following condition holds: for every $x\in A$, there is exactly one $y\in A$ such that $(x, y)\in R$.

Comment: Also, what is $A$? $R$ may be a function(/map) from some $A$ to $A$, e.g. $A=\Bbb R$, the real numbers, but not for other $A$, e..g $A=\{0\}$. Perhaps in your actual problem you have various $A$s to consider; if that's the case, what are some?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R \subseteq A \times B$ be a relation. $R$ is *not* a function if and only if there exist $(x, y) \in R$ and $(x, y') \in R$ with $y \ne y'$.

In the example given above, if $(x,y), (x, y') \in R$, then $x = y+2, x = y' + 2$, so $y=y'$, so this one indeed comes from a function.